# View_messages "class"

Tags: javascript

```
/**
 *    View_message
 *    Object Model
 */ 

var View_message = function(div)
{
    this.div = document.getElementById(div); 
};

View_message.prototype.messages = 
{ 
    empty: 'Please complete all fields',
    empty_bm: 'Please enter both a title and url',
    name: 'Only letters or dashes for the name field',
    email: 'Please enter a valid email',
    same: 'Please make emails equal',
    taken: 'Sorry that email is taken',
    pass: 'Please enter a valid password, 6-40 characters',
    validate: 'Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:support@host.com">support</a> to reset your password',
    url:  'Pleae enter a valid url'
}; 

View_message.prototype.display = function(type) 
{
    this.div.innerHTML = this.messages[type];
};
```

**And the Call**

```
obj_view = new View_message('test_id');
obj_view.display('empty');
```

Comment: Your using `.innerHTML` instead of `.textContent`

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are overcomplicating things. Declaring a prototype, will not make your code any more robust or even faster. I'm sure you know, but actually something like the code below will be easier to read, more effective and also faster.

```
/**
 *    View_message
 *    Object Model
 */ 
var ViewMessage = function(div) {
    this.div = document.getElementById(div); 

    this.messages = { 
        empty: 'Please complete all fields',
        empty_bm: 'Please enter both a title and url',
        name: 'Only letters or dashes for the name field',
        email: 'Please enter a valid email',
        same: 'Please make emails equal',
        taken: 'Sorry that email is taken',
        pass: 'Please enter a valid password, 6-40 characters',
        validate: 'Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:support@host.com">support</a> to reset your password',
        url:  'Pleae enter a valid url'
    };

    this.display = function(type) {
        this.div.innerHTML = this.messages[type];

        return this;
    };

    return this;
};
```

Then two ways of doing this:

```
var view = new ViewMessage('divID');
    view.display('email');
```

OR

```
var view = new ViewMessage('divID').display('email');
```

Comment: Do I even need to set it to a variable?  Could I just do new ViewMessage('divID').display('email')

Comment: No need to set it in a variable, no. But if you want to add more functions later, or anything, well you might need it.. Otherwise, initialise and fire it up! (without the new)
ViewMessage('divID').display('email');

Comment: @lcampanis When instantiating multiple instances, adding methods to the prototype is much faster: http://jsperf.com/instance-vs-prototype-methods

Comment: No doubt it is, but in this case I'm afraid it isn't the case. One instance seems to be needed alone. And sure it might be faster to use the prototype, but on one instance, the delay (if any) we are talking about is almost nothing. 
No doubt it is though, if many are needed, and you intend to loop an enormous amount of time to get things done :)